# Search bar for table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to have 2 tables in one view controller and to make a search only in one of them. How can i do  ?

I know how to  implement search bar , but I don't know how to make a difference between tables. I was trying to do this with tags, but is not working.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

```
UITableViewCell *cell ;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    if (tableView.tag==1) {

   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
    }}
    else if (tableView.tag==0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [historique objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    return cell;

}
```

i was trying also this :

and even if i put like this

```
self.tableSource= self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView; the result is the same
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variables to handle the two tables.

Then you can perform actions only on the one you want.

Exemple :

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *searchableTableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *nonSearchableTableView;
@end
```

Comment: i did this , but when i want to search something the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called and the table where the search will be done is nonSearchableTableView

Comment: CAn you post how you make the search. Did you implemented yourself ? Because I tried this and I don't have any issue. I call cellForRowAtIndexPath on the _searchableTableView by code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two properties for both table view.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table2;
```

Then implement delegate methods of table view

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     if([tableView isEqual:table1])
     {
        return YOUR_VALUE;
     }
     else
     {
        return YOUR_VALUE;
     }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if([tableView isEqual:table1])
{
    return [array1 count]
}
else
{
        return [array2 count];
}
```

Same way implement the cellForRowAtIndexPath method of delegate.

Comment: create property for both the table views and using the property name you can distinguish between the tables. like above code   ---  if([tableView isEqual:table1])

Comment: try to debug using breakpoints.i think you are missing something here